# How to "inject" lines into a here doc redirect?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, sh

I have a BASH function `execute` that establishes a connection over SSH to a machine and executes a bunch of commands provided via here doc redirect. That works great. Is there a way to inject some commands into the redirect? I would like to run always `prepare_something` before e.g. `do_something`.

```
function execute() {
    ssh user@host /bin/bash
}

execute << EOF
    do_something
EOF
```

Comment: A more tangible example would be helpful. Are you just looking to concatenate strings or combine them?

Comment: Give an example of how you want it to work, especially where you want to provide your commands to your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subshell to combine an echo with a `cat` that consumes the stdin of the function. Then the output of the subshell becomes the input of your ssh command.

```
function execute() {
    ( echo prepare_something ; cat ) | ssh user@host /bin/bash
}
```

Comment: ++; not that it will make any tangible difference in practice, but a _group command_ will do in lieu of a subshell: `{ echo prepare_something; cat; }`

Comment: @mklement0, yes, good suggestion. A group command doesn't create a new process.

Comment: Thank you Bill! That works perfect! @mklement0 thanks for teaching me the group command!